# Support for OAuth 2.0 PKCE

Tags: apigee

Is there support for [Proof Key for Code Exchange by OAuth Public Clients](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7636) on Apigee cloud? I couldn't find any reference to it on the online documentation. If not supported, is it on the roadmap?

Answer (score 1):

this should be fairly simple to do, all you need is to create the proper policies in your oauth proxies... we have a solution for openid connect on top of apigee and just added this in a few hours.

PKCE just requires that you store the code_challenge in a cache you can retrieve when about to create the access token, and then it requires you be able to re create from code_verifier + method... this can be done with a node backend, or by importing the proper libraries in a JS callout ( or java callout if that is your thing.)
we used node for this